# How to envelop an image created by a execCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, execcommand

```html
<input type="button" onclick="document.execCommand('insertimage',null,'http://barwoncopiers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/linkedin-icon-45x45.jpg');" value="Img"/>
<br>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor" id="editor"></div>

---

<qwe><img></qwe>
```

If the image is created, I want to automatically enclose the tag.

how < qwe > tag create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below to test if execution is true

```
if (document.execCommand('insertimage', null, 'http://barwoncopiers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/linkedin-icon-45x45.jpg'))
```

when you position cursor in edit box and click on button, note how the if statement is executed with tags enclosing your images (see inspector tools)

```js
document.getElementById("input").onclick = function() {
  if (document.execCommand('insertimage', null, 'http://barwoncopiers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/linkedin-icon-45x45.jpg')) {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("img[src$='wp-content/uploads/2011/03/linkedin-icon-45x45.jpg']");
    for (var x = 0; x < images.length; ++x) {
      if (images[x].parentNode.tagName != "QWE") {
        images[x].outerHTML = "<qwe>" + images[x].outerHTML + "</qwe>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="button" value="Img" id="in" />
<br>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor" id="editor">hh</div>
```

Comment: The image is not inserted when uploading the html file to the server.                 Do you have any added sources of sauce?